# Changing a site Collection URL

Tags: 2010, site-collection

When I created my site collection we called it /sites/teama. The business has changed the name of teama to teamb. How can I change the URL for our site collection.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a root site collection, you will need to do the change the URL  in two places:
**Alternate access mappings** - In central admin modify the alternate access mappings from sites/teama to /sites/teamb

IIS bindings : Modify the binding in IIS for the web application from /sites/teama to /sites/teamb

Or alternatively you can try the following commands:

```
stsadm -o backup -url http://servername/sites/teama -overwrite -filename team.dat
stsadm -o deletesite -url http://servername/sites/teama 
stsadm -o restore -url http://servername/sites/teamb -filename team.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one (min. SP1 on MOSS2007)

`STSADM -renamesite -oldUrl xxx -newUrl yyy` (see here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263038(v=office.12).aspx)

Has no direct equivalent in Powershell, but there is `Set-SPSite` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607958.aspx)

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius